# Firebase query works on emulator but returns empty on cloud

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am running a firebase query to fetch some products that belong to a category. When using the emulator everything runs fine. However when deploying to cloud the query returns empty (`queryProducts.empty === true`), so no product is retrieved.

```js
const prodRef = collection(firestore, ownerPath + '/products')
const prodQuery = query(
        prodRef,
        where('category', '==', category.id),
        where('available', '>', 0)
    )
const queryProducts = await getDocs(prodQuery)
```

I have this index created in firestore to handle the query:
[image]

I have double checked that the info I am trying to retrieve exists and that the ids are all correct. But still nothing.

I have found a [related issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4701) in Github where the emulator has a different behaviour from the cloud environment and added this question there. However I have seen really good answers about firebase here so I was hoping someone could help.

### Update

I have made a few tests and I see this returns products:

```js
const prodQuery = query(
        prodRef,
        where('available', '>', 0)
    )
```

But these doesn't

```js
// The original query
const prodQuery = query(
        prodRef,
        where('category', '==', category.id),
        where('available', '>', 0)
    )

// Query only by cat id
const prodQuery = query(
        prodRef,
        where('category', '==', category.id)
    )
```

So probably there is something going on with the categories. To discard this take this product for example

[image]

The product category is `l6pIKdB5E13uTXepSm1P`

So I manually inserted it in the query and still got an empty result:

```js
const prodQuery = query(
        prodRef,
        where('category', '==', "l6pIKdB5E13uTXepSm1P"),
        where('available', '>', 0)
    )
```

I believe the issue comes from the index. I do not have indexes in the emulator and everything works just fine. However, in firebase cloud they are required so I do not think there is a workaround for it.

Comment: Can you check firebase permission rules. Sometimes you have read write permission until a time. if time passed you see the data but you can retrive it.

Comment: Without seeing the values of all the variables here (ownerPath and category.id) and the actual matching document data, we can't tell you whether or not this is going to work as you expect.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to duplicate the issue.  Firestore queries don't just fail to return documents without a clear error message saying what went wrong. If your index or security rules are problematic, you will definitely get an error message about that, so if there is no error, then the query really did return no matching documents.

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you. I updated the question to provide more information. No, there are no errors in the console. `queryProducts.size is 0` . The `ownerPath` is constant for almost all queries and all of them work so I do not think there is an issue with it. This is the only compound query so far and is the only one giving problems.

Comment: @MustafaSAHINAYDIN thanks, I just double checked and that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot it looks like there is some sort of whitespace before and after the actual category string inside the quotes.  Compare that to the string just below it where there is no visible space in the quotes.  It seems to me that your category names simply do not match between the document and the code.

Comment: Well... and that was my embarrassing moment of the day... hahahah thanks a lot !